# How do I fix an undefined variable in my program?

Tags: applescript, syntax-error

I am a beginner when it comes to AppleScript. I'm trying to develop a program that can generate an actually random number. When I set the values of the numbers that will be used to generate the random number, the editor gives me an error:

> The variable numberOne is not defined.

I know what this means, but I don't know why it isn't defined. Can someone help with this?

I've tried seeing if only strings would work instead of text, but that doesn't seem to do it. There could be a really easy fix to this, but as I said, I'm a beginner.

```
on variableValue()
    set numberOne to text returned of (display dialog "Variable One:" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 with title "Random Number Generator 3") as string
    set numberTwo to text returned of (display dialog "Variable Two:" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 with title "Random Number Generator 3") as string
    set numberThree to text returned of (display dialog "Variable Three:" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 with title "Random Number Generator 3") as string
    set numberFour to text returned of (display dialog "Variable Four:" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 with title "Random Number Generator 3") as string
    set numberFive to text returned of (display dialog "Variable Five:" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 with title "Random Number Generator 3") as string
    set useSameValues to button returned of (display alert "Use same values?" message "If you re-generate a new number, do you want to use the same values?" as critical buttons {"Cancel", "No", "Yes"} default button 3)
    if useSameValues = "No" then
        set useSameValuesTwo to "false"
    else if useSameValues = "Yes" then
        set useSameValuesTwo to "true"
    end if
end variableValue
variableValue()
on randomNumber()
    -- The line of code just beneath this text is where the error shows up (This is my first program that utilizes handlers, so something could be wrong there).
    set numberSix to (numberOne + numberTwo + numberThree + numberFour + numberFive)
    set numberSeven to (numberSix * (random number from 1 to (random number from 2 to 100)))
    set possibleValueOne to (random number from 1 to 5)
    if possibleValueOne = 1 then
        set numberEight to (numberSeven - numberOne)
    else if possibleValueOne = 2 then
        set numberEight to (numberSeven - numberTwo)
    else if possibleValueOne = 3 then
        set numberEight to (numberSeven - numberThree)
    else if possibleValueOne = 4 then
        set numberEight to (numberSeven - numberFour)
    else if possibleValueOne = 5 then
        set numberEight to (numberSeven - numberFive)
    end if
    set numberNine to (numberEight - 100000)
end randomNumber
randomNumber()
```

Comment: It isn't possible to generate an "actually random" number using a software algorithm.  But I commend the experiment and its use to learn about handlers. You could try and implement the [Cliff Random Number Generator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CliffRandomNumberGenerator.html), which will be a great handler to figure out whilst also learning about the maths behind pseudorandomness, and give you clues as to why your script doesn't increase randomness at all over simply using `random number`. But great question and context, with pure geek motivation. +1 to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppleScript (like most languages), variables have a [scope](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_variables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH223-SW1), which is where a declared identifier is recognized within any given script object.  Variables declared inside a handler are local to that handler and don't exist outside of it, so you will need to provide some means to make them available elsewhere.  There are a few ways to do this, such as declaring global variables or **properties**, or having a handler return values to the caller.

In your example, the variables declared in your `variableValue()` handler are not available outside the handler, so it would probably be the easiest to just declare those variables as **global**, for example by adding the following declaration at the beginning of your script:

```
global numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree, numberFour, numberFIve
```

Comment: "Easiest", but not something I'd encourage, especially to newbies.  In AppleScript, there is almost no convincing reason to declare a top-level global variable. It's an excellent way to lose track of one's identifiers, potentiating the likelihood of overwriting values accidentally; makes debugging more difficult; and makes a script less readable. Instead, having one handler return a value, and another accept parameters is not only best practice, but inline with the OP's first venture into using handlers that he's looking to be educated about.

Comment: True.  Since this appears to be a learning script (there is a lot going on to just generate a random number), instead of rewriting the whole thing I just left it alone and went with answering the question at hand.

Comment: I got that sense but it's the learning scripts that are the ones that you _don't_ just answer the question at hand: **a)** they rarely tick, and never +1; **b)** a lazy answer directly compromises their learning at an early stage, and sets them up to progress slowly, or fail.  But this isn't the norm for you, as I'm actually a fan of your answers generally speaking.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! As a beginner, I really appreciate people who help with my AppleScript 'needs'. Thank you for the advice on the random number generator! Thank you!